# Is there a linux equivalent for fpsetmask()?

Tags: linux, centos, bsd

I'm porting some BSD code to CentOS, and I find that the standard function fpsetmask() found in ieeefp.h has been used in the code.

I'm not yet aware of this function's behaviour, but is there a linux equivalent of this? Or should I create something that emulates this on linux?

Answer (score 1):

I think the feraiseexcept() function is the equivalent – for details, look at the “Exception handling” subsection of [its manpage](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=feraiseexcept).

According to [the fpsetmask() manpage](https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man3/fpsetmask.htm), the mapping of the individual flags is as follows:

- FP_X_INV → FE_INVALID
- FP_X_DZ → FE_DIVBYZERO
- FP_X_OFL → FE_OVERFLOW
- FP_X_UFL → FE_UNDERFLOW
- FP_X_IMP → FE_INEXACT
- FP_X_IOV → *none, possibly FE_OVERFLOW too*

Do remember that this is probably x87-only.